# How to find the tangent vector of a potential function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For example, suppose I have the following potential function in $2$-D $$V(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2+x_2^2$$

I know that the gradient vector of $V$ is $\nabla V$; its direction is perpendicular to the level curve at each point. $$\nabla V = \begin{bmatrix}2x_1 \\ 2x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is how to find the tangent vector tangent to the curve at each point with the "form" like the gradient vector?

Is there a general rule to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: What about $t_1 =\left[ 2x_2 ,-2x_1 \right]^T$ or with different orientation $t_2 =\left[-2x_2 ,2x_1 \right]^T$?

Comment: "the curve at each point" can you explain what curve(s) you're talking about?

Comment: @MarkS. the curve means the level curve, i.e., $\{x: V(x) = c\}$, where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: @ConvexHull It looks like we can only get the answer after finding the gradient vector

Comment: Sure, normal an tangential vectors are equivalent in the sense of vector spaces. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space. Normal vectors are defined orthogonal to the tangent space.